# Can you have multiple PHP 5.x versions with cPanel 11.3x?

Tags: apache-2.2, php

I've been Googling around for a while on this one but I haven't found a good answer yet!

Is it possible to set up cPanel 11.3x so that it can run different versions of PHP 5.x (e.g. 5.2, 5.3 and later on 5.4) for each of the configured apache vhosts / domains?

It would be great to do this either using .htaccess, php.ini or a setting within cPanel itself.

I've seen EasyApache 3 mentioned in the documentation but even after reading through several times I haven't seen a definitive yes or no for whether this is possible - please let me know if you need any more info.

This was the documentation I found for EA3: http://goo.gl/IH1sP

Comment: I just wanted to update this to say that Plesk 11.5 now supports multiple versions of PHP on Linux

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have multiple instances of PHP installed on your server at once (usually), but alas, apache can only have one mod_php loaded at a time.  Therefore, no, you cannot do this.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to have multiple PHP versions in cPanel.

There is already a [feature request](http://features.cpanel.net/responses/allow-to-install-multiple-php-5x-versions) for cPanel and an extensive discussion at cPanel forum [post](http://forums.cpanel.net/f145/multiple-php-5-x-versions-case-55764-a-136101.html) with some approaches to run multiple PHP versions.

In case of Cloudlinux you can make use of the [PHP selector](http://docs.cloudlinux.com/php_selector.html) component.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. You can't do it with mod_php but if you want to manually hack the vhost configs you can do it.